# Azure Data Factory passing a parameter into a function (string replace)

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF to create azure table storage tables from one source SQL table.

- Within my pipeline..

  - I can query a distinct list of customers pass this into a for-each
    task.
  - Inside the for each select the data for each customer

But when I try to to create an Azure table for each customers data with the table name based on the customer ID I hit errors.
The customer ID is a GUID so I'm trying to format this to remove the dashes which are invalid in a table name...

Something along the lines of 
@replace('@{item().orgid}','-','')

So  7fb6d90f-2cc0-40f5-b4d0-00c82b9935c4 becomes 7fb6d90f2cc040f5b4d000c82b9935c4

I can't seem to get the syntax right
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `@replace(item().orgid,'-','').`